# Trouble Using indexOf While Looping Through a Word Checking for Matching Letters

Tags: javascript, indexof

Please help me think this through... I am trying to check and see if all of the letters in the second element of an array are contained within the letters of the first element, ignoring case. So "Aliens" and "lines" should return true because all of the letters in "lines" are included in "Aliens" even though they are not in order. My problem is when I try to loop through the first element my code appears to only be checking the first letter for a match and not continuing through the entire word.

```
function mutation(arr) {
  var firstElement = arr[0].toLowerCase().split('');
  var secondElement = arr[1].toLowerCase().split('');
  for (var i = 0; i < firstElement.length; i++) {
    return firstElement.indexOf(secondElement[i]) != -1;
  }
}
mutation(["hello", "neo"]);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: do you have an array of arrays or an array of strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with the function:

Firstly, it is returning after checking only the first letter, as you say.

Secondly, you need to use the length of the second element as your loop termination condition, since that's the one whose letters you are intending to loop through.

You need something more like this:

```
function mutation(arr) {
  var firstElement = arr[0].toLowerCase().split('');
  var secondElement = arr[1].toLowerCase().split('');
  for (var i = 0; i < secondElement.length; i++) {
     if(firstElement.indexOf(secondElement[i]) === -1) {
         return true;
     }
  }
  return false;
}
```

You might also want to handle some obvious boundary cases, like null/undefined/empty strings, but I've left that out for clarity.

Comment: Thanks, I had something similar with an else return false, but placing the return false outside of the loop is what I needed. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

it's checking only for the first letter because as it enters into the loop, the **return** statement gets executed, and hence the function terminates.

```
function mutation(arr) {
  var firstElement = arr[0];
  var secondElement = arr[1];
  return secondElement.split('').every(function(elem) {return  firstElement.indexOf(elem) != -1;} );
}
mutation(["Aliens", "lines"]);
```

Comment: That's some sweet code and it accomplishes what I am trying to do when ignoring case, but I am not familiar with the .every method. Looks like a nice way to avoid an unnecessary for-loop though which was an eloquent goal I had when starting this problem. Cheers

Comment: **every** method of an array return true if every element of array satisfy the callback method(if returns **true**).
For more info, see this.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` and `reduce` in order to save lines of code

```
function mutation(arr) {
  var secondElement = arr[1].toLowerCase().split('');
  var map = secondElement.map(function(a){return arr[0].indexOf(a) != -1});
  return map.reduce(function(a,b) {return a&&b;}, true);
}
```

On second line you check if each letter from second word is in first word (and save true/false). Third line just accumulate those results into a final variable

Reference 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Array/reduce
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Array/map

Comment: That's pretty sweet, I need to read up on map, it seems to be pretty useful, just hard for me to conceptualize at this point.

Comment: yeah those are pretty useful functions, you should give it a try. Hope it's useful, have a good day

Answer (score 0):

Don't split the first element -- treat it as a string and use the indexOf method on that with the single characters from the second element.

Update -- yes, like Depperm's code below, but throw a toLowerCase on firstElement.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that is giving me the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Using what Paul Kienitz mentioned, also change your loop to loop through the second element to check each character in the first element to see if it finds that character in the first element.

```js
function mutation(arr) {
  var firstElement = arr[0];
  var secondElement = arr[1].toLowerCase().split('');
  var match=true;
  var temp;
  for (var i = 0; i < secondElement.length; i++) {
    temp = firstElement.indexOf(secondElement[i]);
    if(temp==-1)
      match=false;
  }
  return match;
}
mutation(["hello", "neo"]);
```